# Too many values to unpack, matplotlib.pyplot.quiver

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot two side by side quivers, however, it seems to fail on the first one, with the error message `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` I have looked into the matplotlib files, and it appears to be an error in checking the size of my quiver U argument. Could anybody help me out? Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

spring_const = 20
mass = 1
initial_length = 1
mu = 3
g = 9.81

size, spacing = 10, 0.5

gamma = theta, theta_dot, length, length_dot = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-size, size, spacing), np.arange(-size, size, spacing), np.arange(-size, size, spacing), np.arange(-size, size, spacing))

theta_2dot = (1/(length+1e-10)) * (g * ((theta*np.cos(theta) - np.sin(theta))) + ((spring_const / mass)*theta*(initial_length - length)) - ((mu / mass)*(length_dot**2)*((theta_dot**2) + 1)) - (length_dot*theta_dot))
length_2dot = ((spring_const / mass)*(length - initial_length)) - (g*np.cos(theta))

nabla_gamma = theta_dot, theta_2dot, length_dot, length_2dot

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

for i in gamma:
    print(i.shape)
print("")
for i in nabla_gamma:
    print(i.shape)

ax0.quiver(theta, theta_dot, theta_dot, theta_2dot)
ax1.quiver(length, length_dot, length_dot, length_2dot)

plt.show()
```

And here is what python outputs, including errors:

```
(40, 40, 40, 40)
(40, 40, 40, 40)
(40, 40, 40, 40)
(40, 40, 40, 40)

(40, 40, 40, 40)
(40, 40, 40, 40)
(40, 40, 40, 40)
(40, 40, 40, 40)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\FILES\Programming\python\Maths\Vector Fields\main.py", line 27, in <module>
    ax0.quiver(theta, theta_dot, theta_dot, theta_2dot)
  File "matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1459, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5167, in quiver
    q = mquiver.Quiver(self, *args, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "matplotlib\quiver.py", line 478, in __init__
    X, Y, U, V, C = _parse_args(*args, caller_name='quiver')
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "matplotlib\quiver.py", line 423, in _parse_args
    nr, nc = (1, U.shape[0]) if U.ndim == 1 else U.shape
    ^^^^^^
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I added the `print(i.shape)` parts to try and figure out if there was an error with the size of the arrays. but theyre all the same so I am very confused.

Comment: The problem line works if `U` is 1d or 2d.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with the shape of the input arrays for the quiver function. The quiver function expects 2D arrays for its arguments, but in your code, theta, theta_dot, theta_2dot, length, length_dot, and length_2dot are all 4D arrays. You can try reshaping these arrays to 2D before passing them to the quiver function

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

spring_const = 20
mass = 1
initial_length = 1
mu = 3
g = 9.81

size, spacing = 10, 0.5

gamma = theta, theta_dot, length, length_dot = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-size, size, spacing), np.arange(-size, size, spacing), np.arange(-size, size, spacing), np.arange(-size, size, spacing))

theta_2dot = (1/(length+1e-10)) * (g * ((theta*np.cos(theta) - np.sin(theta))) + ((spring_const / mass)*theta*(initial_length - length)) - ((mu / mass)*(length_dot**2)*((theta_dot**2) + 1)) - (length_dot*theta_dot))
length_2dot = ((spring_const / mass)*(length - initial_length)) - (g*np.cos(theta))

nabla_gamma = theta_dot, theta_2dot, length_dot, length_2dot

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

for i in gamma:
    print(i.shape)
print("")
for i in nabla_gamma:
    print(i.shape)

theta = theta.reshape((theta.shape[0], -1))
theta_dot = theta_dot.reshape((theta_dot.shape[0], -1))
theta_2dot = theta_2dot.reshape((theta_2dot.shape[0], -1))
length = length.reshape((length.shape[0], -1))
length_dot = length_dot.reshape((length_dot.shape[0], -1))
length_2dot = length_2dot.reshape((length_2dot.shape[0], -1))

ax0.quiver(theta, theta_dot, theta_dot, theta_2dot)
ax1.quiver(length, length_dot, length_dot, length_2dot)

plt.show()
```